# Run "truffle test" command with auto set custom balances

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc, truffle-config

I know how to set custom balance accounts on testrpc.
It could be like `$ testrpc --account="0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57,100000000000000000000"`.
But I don't figure out how to do that with "truffle test".
Are there any way to configure account balances?

Comment: I don't know why you want to do this, however you can simply burn them in a `before` block.

Answer (score 1):

When running truffle test it will use testrpc as default network. So, in order to configure account balances you would do it as you are doing now.
Truffle test will connect to testrpc and use the accounts in there.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. Is there a way do same thing without manually launching testrpc?

Comment: Truffle 4.0 introduced their own test environment which you can launch by executing truffle develop. More info here: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases

Comment: Yes, actually I read this page. But I don't figure out how to run "truffle test" command with auto setted custom balances. Maybe balances are not configurable?